# PL/SQL: Statement ignored and PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type in the return

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have probelm in my PL SQL tesk with oracle 11g.
My task is discount 20% if audio CDs released more than one year ago.
I so I made this statement

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY disk_type AS
OVERRIDING MEMBER FUNCTION discountPrice RETURN NUMBER IS
    BEGIN
      IF 
         albumReleaseDate > to_char(trunc(SYSDATE - interval '1' year,'YEAR'),'YYYYMM') 
         AND  mediaType = 'Audio CD'
         THEN RETURN albumPrice = (albumPrice * 0.8);
      END IF;
    END discountPrice;
END;
```

However, I got this error message

```
7/15      PL/SQL: Statement ignored
7/33      PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
```

the messages say my return datatype is wrong

This  my supertype

```
    create or replace type album_type as object 
(albumTitle         varchar(50),
 albumPlaytime      number(3), -- minutes
 albumReleaseDate   date, 
 albumGenre         varchar(15),
 albumPrice         number(9,2),
 albumTracks        number(2),
 albumArtists       artist_array_type,
 albumReviews       review_table_type,
member function discountPrice return number,
member function containsText (pString1 varchar2, pString2 varchar2) return integer)
not instantiable not final
/
create table albums of album_type 
object id system generated
 /
```

This is my subtype

```
    create or replace type disk_type under album_type 
( mediaType         varchar(10), -- Audio CD wull be 'Audio CD'
 diskNum            number(2), -- number of disks
 diskUsedPrice      number(9,2),
 diskDeliveryCost   number(9,2), 
overriding member function discountPrice return number)
/
```

Comment: Oh I for got. I have to return the discounted price not a update

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the variable via `RETURN` clause. assignment of value to the variable must be separate logic.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY disk_type AS
OVERRIDING MEMBER FUNCTION discountPrice RETURN NUMBER IS
    BEGIN
      IF 
         albumReleaseDate > to_char(trunc(SYSDATE - interval '1' year,'YEAR'),'YYYYMM') 
         AND  mediaType = 'Audio CD'
         THEN return (albumPrice * 0.8); -- direct return, no assignment
      END IF;
      Return albumPrice; -- added this
    END discountPrice;
END;
```

You can achieve this using simple case statement also:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY disk_type AS
OVERRIDING MEMBER FUNCTION discountPrice RETURN NUMBER IS
    BEGIN
       Return albumPrice * ( case 
              when albumReleaseDate > to_char(trunc(SYSDATE - interval '1' year,'YEAR'),'YYYYMM') 
                   AND  mediaType = 'Audio CD'
         THEN 0.8
         ELSE 1 END)
    END discountPrice;
END;
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Think you so much!